# Solutions for Project management

Tags: project-management, agile

- The team consists of **3** people.
- The method of development is **Scrum**.
- The language of the project is **C++**.
- The project will be under the control of the **git** system.
- The start up budget is **0**.

**The following things have to be chosen:**

1. Build and Version Numbering
2. Project documentation ( file with the most common info for current stage of the project, which will be changed every time the new version or subversion of the project emerges )
3. Project management tool ( like Trac or Redmine, I cannot use them, because there is no hosting )
4. Code documentation ( I consider Doxygen )

**The following questions have arisen:**

1. What can you add to the above list of the main solutions for project management in the described project?
2. One of three project participants has linux os (No MS Office), one has Windows and MS Office (does not want to use Libre or Open Office), one has Windows, but does not have MS Office. What formats, tools can u suggest using for project documentation? The variant of using online wiki does not fit, it must be files.
3. OneNote mb is a good tool for project management, but because of the reason mentioned above it is not possible. What can you advise?
4. Offer a system for Build and Version Numbering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [Semantic Versioning](http://semver.org/) for version numbering.
2. You could use a wiki for developer information and that is not a bad idea, but with only three people I would probably just put it in the git repo and roll it into something else if/when the number of people grow.
3. I would normally say Redmine for project management, but if you do not have a server there are two other options. The first is to sign up for something on the web that does what you want. You could put your project on github (signing up for a private account, if necessary). If a server is completely out of the question I would use [ditz](http://ditz.rubyforge.org/). It plays nicely with git and puts all of the bug/task tracking information in your repository.
4. Doxygen seems reasonable enough for API docs. It isn't well suited to anything else, though.

> What formats, tools can u suggest using for project documentation?

It may seem a little old school, but you could just use Markdown for project documentation. Everyone should be able to work with plain text. If you want something fancier, you could then run it through Pandoc to produce HTML, OpenOffice or MS Word versions of the document. If that is not an option, RTF should be supported by pretty much every format.

Comment: If you dont want to run redmine on windows use a virtual machine (like virtualbox) and load it with those project management aspects: issue tracking/planning, master source repo, etc.  Doing this could give you some flexability about what platform and tools you incorporate into your process.

Answer (score 0):

Rally for the project management, Tiddlywiki for the documentation and not Doxygen which I find tends to be write-only. Perforce is good for source control but you have already chosen git.